# Can't change the color of toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, toolbar

Can anyone please, explain me, why my toolbar doesn't change its color even though I created another style like:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>
```

added it in my manifest file like:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SettingsActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.com.com.com.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

and try to change the toolbar like:

```
Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar(this);
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_blue));
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

but still get

> This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor.
>   Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to
>   false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

I even tried to `getSupportActionBar().hide();` but still doesn't work.

XML :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.com.com.com.SettingsActivity"
    android:id="@+id/settings_activity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Basically, what I want is to keep my global theme and just change toolbar color in one of the activities. That is why I don't create a toolbar inside xml file, I create it programmatically, add background color and want to set it.

Comment: The theme does not go in the `<meta-data>`. It goes in the opening `<activity>`. tag.

Comment: Can you post your xml file with the Toolbar element you want to change?

Comment: I think, you first need to add `Toolbar`. `rootElement.add(toolbar)`. than set it as `setSupportActionBar`.

Comment: @Ka7Im1011 I added xml file, please check it. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to take off `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"`  outside the `meta-data` tag :

```
  <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="net.noorr.menote.menote.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

And in java code:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.yourToolbarId);
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_blue));
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: I don't want to change my whole application theme. I want to change in only one activity

Comment: I did, but what happens is a white blank screen

Comment: I solved it an another way, gave up to do it programmatically. But my main problem was that my theme was inside meta tags and your answer put me to the right direction I think. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting your toolbar in the wrong way. You're probably not extending `Toolbar` class.
Try to get it directly by the id defined in the xml file.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
```

Then you can set it as support and eventually set your color.

**Edit**:
Didn't see you're creating it programmatically.
Try to set a simple AppTheme style like

```
<style name="NoToolbarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Umm, I think no, as I don't findViewById, I create new toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below code helps you...

Create the theme in your styles.xml as follow:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Make sure you have this in your gradle dependencies

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"
```

In your layout xml files add this toolbar tag

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#2196F3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In your manifest file add the theme you created to the acctivity

```
<activity
        android:name="com.javatechig.sample.MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

And finally, here is your activity

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    // Set a toolbar to replace the action bar.
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but it doesn't work. And ActionBarActivity is deprecated

Comment: @Elnoor what do u mean by it does not work. Does it crash or the tool bar does not show up ?

Comment: @Elnoor Instead of ActionBarActivity you can also use AppCompatActivity, have edited the ans as well. Please refer to http://javatechig.com/android/android-lollipop-toolbar-example for moe explanation

Comment: toolbar appears but all the space white event notification area. What i want to keep my theme and just change toolbars color

Comment: I use AppCompatActivity anyways, i mentioned it because it was in your code

Comment: @Elnoor in the toolbar tag change the background color

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

here's `styles.xml` contains custom theme.

```
<resources>

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"></style>

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

`AndroidManifest.xml` contains custom theme for `SettingActivity`

```
<activity
    android:name=".SettingActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_setting"
    android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >
</activity>
```

`Layout` file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/settingRootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.demo.SettingActivity" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

finally your Activity file

```
package com.example.demo;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class SettingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RelativeLayout rootLayout;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);
        rootLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.settingRootLayout);
        mToolbar = new Toolbar(this);
        mToolbar.setLayoutParams(
                new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        mToolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_blue));
        mToolbar.setFitsSystemWindows(true);
        rootLayout.addView(mToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    }

}
```

Comment: Still didn't work @Ka7Im1011. I get white notification area.