# Android - invisible ActionBar with back button

Tags: android

I know how to implment `ActionBar` with back button. But I want to make `ActionBar` invisible or with no background, I want to have only visible back button arrow. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't change the color of toolbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33718557/cant-change-the-color-of-toolbar)

Comment: you can find transparent color in android resources android.R.color.transparent, or just use #00000000

Answer (score 1):

With a little of search you will find the response. Any way you can try this :

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00000000")));
```

If you want to have your tab background below your ActionBar add this too :

```
actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00000000")));
```

Comment: That is what I had tried before I wrote my topic but I see white background behind it so I tried to add this code `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);` to overlay activity content but I have the same result.

Comment: I've already marked this as duplicate int the original question there is a solution already